# Wordpress theme.json - Border Top?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to apply a border to the top of a dropdown submenu, but i can only find syntax for setting the border for every side.  is there a way to set up a border for ONLY the top in theme.json

Answer (score 0):

```
   {
  "dropdownSubmenu": {
    "borderTop": "1px solid #000"
  }
}
```